# Does it make trouble to reject mails in the smtp dialog when users use forwarding?

Tags: email, postfix, spam, forwarding

I have a spam filter, which rejects some mails based on header fields during SMTP dialog with `header_checks` in postfix.

Is it a problem, when a user sets a forward from another server to an address on my server? The other server probably first accepts the mail and then tries to forward it, so it cannot bounce it without creating backscatter.

How does a good configured server react, when it cannot forward the e-mail? While my server should not create a problem for mails sent directly to it, I am not sure what would be the right way for the forwarding server to react and if I make trouble for my users by not accepting mails which were forwarded.

Allowing the user to opt out of the spam filter is not easy possible, as an `OK` in receiver_checks (acceppting the `RCPT TO` command) does not stop `header_checks` execution, which results in REJECT after the `DATA` command.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; no, you should reject it.

Without source address rewriting (where the forwarder accepts responsibility for forwarding spam), you should comply with the original senders SPF/DKIM/DMARC policy and likely Reject it.  New authentication chaining like ARC are still in development.  Also what their server does is not your problem, they should not forward and send notice back to the original user.

Comment: I am not sure about who has a problem now. The user does not get the mail, but the sender does not get feedback about it (if the server does not produce backscatter) and the mail is lost without feedback to sender or receiver. On the other hand, any user could use forwards to this address. And any spammer could setup his own forward.